# Querying a specific column in an Android Database

Tags: android

I have an Android app that has a database. My database has a table say Person Table, which has 4 columns , Firstname, lastname, DOB and Age. How do I go about retrieving just the DOB information for all the rows in the table.

Your help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you google this or search Stack overflow... This is even in the Android docs.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample

Comment: Please see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Specifically, the first section mentions searching for previous answers before asking. In addition, if any of the answers you've received in the past have been correct you should [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) them.

Answer (score 1):

When querying, just specify the columns that you're after:

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String[] cols = {"dob"};

Cursor result = db.query("person", cols, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> DobList = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(String.format("select DOB from %s", TABLE_NAME);
  if (cursor.movetoFirst) {
    do {
      DobList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DOB")));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
cursor.close();
```